# Outputting to multiple attribute fields after Spatial join?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm totally newb to GIS.

I'm trying to perform a spatial join of two polygon layers, and want the results to propagate into two separate attribute fields.  Specifically, I have one polygon layer of municipalities in New York state, and another of electric utility service areas.  Some of those municipalities are bisected by two utilities.  I want to create an attribute table (exportable to csv) that lists each municipality, with one attribute field listing one utility, and the next attribute field listing the second one (if there is one).  (I.e. Bedford / NYSGas&Electric / ConEdison).

When I perform a spatial join now (using QGIS on a Mac), using the spatialjoin plug-in and doing an intersect join type, the output only lists one of the utilities when a municipality is bisected (i.e. Bedford / NYStateGas&Electric).

Any idea how I'd get the results I'm hoping for?

Comment: Part of your post got cut off.